# PHPMailer with Gmail (can I send emails from name@mypersonaldomain.com?)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a [Gmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) account. I.e., myemail@gmail.com.

I have associated my website email to it. I.e., contact@mydomain.com

Is it possible to use PHPMailer to send email via Gmail (for reliability, less likely to get flagged as spam, etc.), but have "contact@mydomain.com" as my sent email?

I'm using the code found here:

*[Send email using Gmail and PHPMailer](http://blog.levhita.net/2008/03/13/send-email-using-gmail-and-phpmailer/)*

So far I've been getting an error:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: Much cleaner way would be to use google apps (gmail for business) feature. You can get upto 50 free ids  (....@mydomain.com) with gmail interface and functionality.

Comment: Please share more details

Comment: You need to use XOAUTH2 for gmail https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Gmail-XOAUTH2-Using-Google-API-Client

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Accounts and Import* in Gmail, *Send mail as* and verify contact@mydomain.com, and then give it a try. First make sure you script is working the "regular way".

You can also buy Gmail for Business (for your domain) and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The example there does not seem to be using SSL which [is required](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287).

```
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

Make sure you have [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) extension turned on in file *php.ini*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting up a free [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) account for mydomain.com and using an email account there to send your email.

You could set up contact@mydomain.com as an account through Google Apps, and then use this as the sender for your email -- the settings for PHPMailer should be the same as for gmail except you would use *contact@mydomain.com* as your username for authentication (and whatever password you set up, obviously).

If you want to forward email sent to contact@mydomain.com to your Gmail account, you can do this [just as you would for a Gmail account](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10957).